# Как отправлять сообщение клиенту через socket в отдельной функции

Tags: python, сервер, сокет

чтобы сервер написал команду и сервер отправил

вот код:

```
import socket
from Server import *
class server_socket():
    def socket(self):
        host = ('0.0.0.0', 7777)
        self.s= socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(host)
        self.s.listen()
        conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        with conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                data = conn.recv(16000)
                if not data:
                    continue
                data_command = data.decode()
                if 'StartS' == data_command:
                    Server_main().cycle()
                    self.conn.send('startSgood'.encode())
                return data.decode()
    def senddate(self, text:str):
        self.s.send(text.encode())
        data = self.s.recv(16000)
        if data:
            return data.decode()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    s = server_socket().socket()
```

Answer (score 0):

Используйте `threading.Thead`, для вынесения асинхронных задач в отдельный поток:

```
import socket
from Server import *
from threading import Thread

class server_socket:
    def socket(self):
        host = ('0.0.0.0', 7777)
        self.s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.s.bind(host)
        self.s.listen()
        self.conn, addr = self.s.accept()
        with self.conn:
            print('Connected by', addr)
            while True:
                data = self.conn.recv(16000)
                if not data:
                    continue
                data_command = data.decode()
                if 'StartS' == data_command:
                    Server_main().cycle()
                    self.conn.send('startSgood'.encode())
                return data.decode()
    def senddate(self, text:str):
        self.s.send(text.encode())
        data = self.s.recv(16000)
        if data:
            return data.decode()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    serve = server_socket()
    threading.Thread(target=server.socket).start() # Запуск в отдельном потоке
    while True:
        serve.conn.send(input().encode())
```

P. S. Очень прошу, нормально организуйте свой код. Соблюдайте принципы ООП.

P. P. S. И лучше, сразу перейдите на прикладные высокоуровневые протоколы. К примеру `HTTP`, `WebSocket`, `RTP`. Они все даже под питон обёрнуты в удобные движки, насколько питон вообще позволяет подобные системы.